# Override built-in types in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I modify the behavior of any dunder method of any class? For example, can I modify the behavior of the `__add__` method of the `str` class? (Totally illogical, but I just want to know if the language is protected from accidental overrides or not.)

Comment: Python does support `super` class inheritance. So, it should work. Hopefully. Just make sure it doesn't affect any other functions

Comment: You could create a subclass of `str` and alter its behaviour with respect to `__add__`, but it would only affect instances of your subclass, not normal strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can monkey-patch a lot, but not anything that's implemented in C, which includes the built-in `str` class.

```
>>> str.__add__ = lambda x, y: 'xyzzy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

Similarly, you can't override `__add__` on `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> defaultdict.__add__ = lambda x, y: 'xyzzy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'collections.defaultdict'
```

Once you get away from the very core, though, you can often override things, even in the standard library:

```
>>> from random import Random
>>> Random.__add__ = lambda x, y: 'xyzzy'
>>> Random() + Random()
'xyzzy'
```

You still can't override things that are implemented in C, even if they're third-party libraries:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.ndarray.__add__ = lambda x, y: 'xyzzy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: PS: looks like there actually is a library for monkey-patching built-in types: [forbiddenfruit](https://pypi.org/project/forbiddenfruit/); never tried it, though